# Woocommerce: why should I use do_action woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item and etc?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am learning woocommerce and trying to loop a list of products. I used the first method and then found the another one that is preferred. The result is the same, but I don't understand why I need to use the second method instead of the first one that is much simpler?

The first method:

```
<div class="col-md-4 product simpleCart_shelfItem text-center">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
<div class="mask">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Quick View</a>
</div>
<a class="product_name" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php if( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ): ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()); ?>" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ) ?>" data-product_sku="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->sku ) ?>" class="item_add <?php echo $class; ?>"><i></i> <span class="item_price"><?php echo $price_html ?></span></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The second method:

```
<div class="col-md-4 product simpleCart_shelfItem text-center">

<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'); ?>       

<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title'); ?>  

<?php do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title'); ?>         

<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you said both method will work for you, but using second method in proper way have big advantage:

if woocommerce update their code or template  you don't need to worry about updating your code accordingly  and to use the second method in proper way first you don't need to copy the template to your theme unless you need to do some  major changes but in your case as you need only to add div  before shop loop item you should do it in this way :

first open your function.php

```
function MyCustomDiv (){
  echo '<div class= "col-md-4 product simpleCart_shelfItem text-center">';
  }

function EndyCustomDiv (){
      echo '</div>';
  }

add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ,  'MyCustomDiv');
add_action ( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ,  'EndyCustomDiv');
```

and to understand more about Wordpres API i suggest to read the following:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: I have two loops of products in one page. Both loops are in different div's blocks.

As I understand, I need to use:

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );

and change wrapper_start.php and wrapper_end.php

But how to change these wrappers' files if I have two loops in one page?

Comment: actually it's only one loop but the hook above allow to add your html markup before the loop start and after the loop finish if you can tell me what exactly you want to achieve i might be able to help more